# Question to be solved using matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

A shopkeeper is convinced that north Indians eat more wheat than rice and south Indians eat more rice than wheat .So he offers two packets say N containing 5kg of wheat and 2kg of rice and second packet S containing 5kg of rice and 2kg of wheat. What do I do if I want 34kg of wheat and only 1kg of rice?

Comment: Please check your question for typos. The two packages you described are the same.

Comment: Are you allowed to buy partial packets?  Each packet contains more than one kilo of rice.

Comment: why is the shopkeeper convinced of this? Is he a bigot?

Comment: @kccu they are not the same, one has 5kg of wheat, the other has 5kg of rice

Answer (score 0):

You can set up your problem as a pair of simultaneous equations, one for total wheat bought and one for total rice bought. $$5N+2S=34\\2N+5S=1$$

Solving this gives a solution with a negative number though, so I am not too sure how this result should be interpreted.

Comment: Perhaps you buy $8$ Northern packets, and from the contents you make up $3$ Southern packets which you sell back to the grocer?